# How to enable userrole object in salesforce

Tags: user

> **Requirement**

I am facing issue when giving permissions for **UserRole** object.

> **Userrole** is the child object for the user object. 
>   Then I came to know child object of parent object, we cannot give
>   permissions like read and write for that particular profile

**But for particular user ,this userrole object  is disabled why?**

Comment: Are you trying to create user record in apex?

Comment: @Devendra for particular profile, userroleid is not creating why?

Comment: Are you receiving any error? Can you please share us screenshot of error message? Any code that you are using? It would be helpful to investigate further.

Comment: Can you check if running User's Profile has access to UserRole records.

Comment: Kindly check @cropredy's answer.  It includes necessary details. For a difference between Profiles, Roles, and Permission Sets check [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_securing_data_roles_profiles.htm). If the answer below or the link shared here in this comment doesn't answer your question, then kindly Edit your question and include more details.

Answer (score 3):

When creating a user, there are two important related objects:

- Profile (via the value in `User.ProfileId`
- UserRole (via the value of `User.UserRoleId`

**For internal users (not portal chatter, or community)**
These relationships are unrelated to each other in the schema - that is, a user for Profile X can be in any UserRole R; a user in UserRole S can be in any Profile P.

When you insert a User, `ProfileId` is required, `UserRoleId` is not. Based on your business requirements, you will need to locate the ProfileId and UserRoleId to look up using SOQL - most likely done in some, on-demand, Utility class method so you can cache the results for the entire transaction in a static variable.

That is, build a map of `Profile.Name` to `Profile`; a map of `UserRole.Name` to `UserRole` (two separate SOQL calls)

Comment: @user36188 - please use the `edit` link on your OP and put in a specific example. Your question is not clear enough

Comment: can you please see this question:http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155126/user-role-in-salesforce         @cropredy

Comment: @user36188 Please use [edit] to amend your question - linking to a different question is not Community best practice

Comment: please see my answer.If my answer is correct , please accept it and my account is blocked now,Guide me to recover my account by voting this question,if it is not correct dont vote me @cropredy

Answer (score 1):

This impact is due to `Spring17` release of Salesforce. There is a Salesforce [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000248644&language=en_US&type=1) with Title **Unable to query on UserRole object after Spring'17** pertaining to this issue but it seems to be broken or at least, it is not showing any **content**.

For Particular user, **View app setup and administrative permissions of system permissions** is disabled in salesforce

If this is disabled, we cannot access the **userrole** object.

After enabling this, **UserRole** object is now accessible.

Comment: @sfdcfox if it is correct,please accept the answer

Comment: @Mahmood Hi I want your Help,can you please join here,http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54520/trigger-if-certain-data-matches-mysql in this room,small query